# Definition 2.2.3 (Convergence of a Sequece) from Abott's Understading Anaylsis

Tags: analysis

[image]

Can anyone explain this definition?

I dont understand what the definition means. What is $N$ ? I know $\mathbb{N}$ is natural numbers. Also, what is $n$?

And why does $n > N$ matter in this definition?

Answer (score 1):

The idea of convergence of a sequence is that there is some point $a$ such that for any distance, all but a finite number of terms in that sequence are within that distance to $a$. $\epsilon$ represents the distance, and a point $a_n$ with $|a_n-a|<\epsilon$ is within that distance from $a$. Assume that all but a finite number of terms in $\{a_n\}$ are within that distance from $a$. Maybe those terms are $a_{j_1}, a_{j_2}...a_{j_k}$, with $j_1<j_2<...j_k$. Then let's say that $j_k=N-1$, so $a_{N-1}$ has the largest index out of all of those terms. Then that means that all $a_n$ with $n>N-1$ or $n\geq N$ is within distance $\epsilon$ from $a$. Here, $N$ is some index such that, if the sequence started at the $N$th term, all points in the sequence would be within distance $\epsilon$ from $a$. $n$ is just any possible index.

Comment: wow ! thank you so much ! I totally understand now.

Answer (score 1):

The letter $n$ is the variable that denotes the number of the element $a_n$ in the sequence $(a_1,a_2,a_3, \ldots)$.

Given such a sequence, say
$$\left(0,{1\over2},{2\over3},{3\over4},{4\over5}\ldots\right)\ ,$$ one often has the feeling that when $n$ gets larger the $a_n$ will be nearer and nearer to a certain number $\alpha$, namely $1$ in this example. The Definition 2.2.3 serves to make such feelings precise, and is the "primordial" codification of a limit.

The sequence
$$\left(0,-{1\over2},{2\over3},-{3\over4},{4\over5},-{5\over6},{6\over7}\ldots\right)\ ,$$
has selected subsequences which also converge to $1$, but we are not inclined to call it convergent. For convergence to some limit $\alpha$ we want that **all** $a_n$ with large $n$ are near  $\alpha$.

Hence the ultimate definition of limit will have to incorporate the ideas of "**arbitrarily close**" to $\alpha$, as well as "**all** $a_n$ with large number $n$ have to be near $\alpha$".

On the other hand we don't want to to specify the speed with which the $a_n$ approximate $\alpha$, say by postulating $|a_n-\alpha|\leq e^{-n}$.

I won't regurgitate Definition 2.2.3 here, but it  exactly fulfills the requirements put forward above: Given any, however small,  tolerance $\epsilon>0$ it is guaranteed that for all $a_n$ with sufficiently large $n$ (that's what the $N$ is about) one has $|a_n-\alpha|<\epsilon$.